# Make a user log in for a host valid for all the other hosts in the same domain

Tags: linux, users, login, authentication, ldap

Assume that several machines with Unix-like OSs are connected to a server, which for example runs LDAP. Its database includes many users: one of them is `testuser`. This way, `testuser` can perform a login in *any* of the machines with the same credentials.

Assume now that `testuser` successfully logged in `host1`. Is it possible to make this login valid also for all the other hosts in the domain, so that, when `testuser` tries to log in them, he is already authenticated?

This should work approximately the following way: each machine belonging to the domain is trusted. When a user logs in a machine, a check is performed if he/she has already logged in another machine of the domain; if no, a password (or key) is required; if yes, user is automatically authenticated also in the current machine.

[Plan 9](https://9p.io/plan9/) offers something similar. Is it possible to obtain this with Unix-like OSs?

---

Edit: by *login* I mean the successful access to the system shell or GUI. Logins may occur remotely, through `ssh`, as well as locally, through a keyboard. The authentication method should be password for a local access, password or key for `ssh`. I would always consider the use of PAM.

Answer (score 0):

When using Kerberos as SSO protocol: If a user logs into his/her workstation there's a ticket-granting ticket (TGT) stored in the user's session (e.g. file). With this TGT the user can obtain service tickets for accessing other "kerberized" services, e.g. SSH servers.

This assumes that your security policy allows all systems to be accessed with a common account.